# How do I add a background image on my DIV tag with CSS

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to set my DIV with a background image, but it's not working for me. The image isn't showing up at all. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="main_wrapper">
        <div id="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, the DIV with the id `"main_wrapper"`, i'd like to have the image I'm using fill up 100% of the screen, and the DIV with the id `"main_content"` I'd like to have a solid color, centered with only 1200px wide.

Here is my CSS:

```
#main_wrapper{
    background-image: url('img/bar_bkgnd.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1920px;
}

#main_content{
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 800px;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

If anyone can help me with this issue, that would be very helpful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Add the `background-size:cover` key / value to your css in the wrapper. Should fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `background-size:cover` to `#main_wrapper`. That should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try this for the image size:

```
#main_wrapper{
 background: url("img/bar_bkgnd.png");
 background-size: 100% 100%;  // or cover like Ben Dyer states
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/8hP4h/**

`#main_wrapper` should be bigger than `#main_content` and try to [not use fixed size](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/).

you can use more effective `em`, `%`, `auto` and others..

Answer (score 0):

In your #main_content, add the following:

```
 margin: auto;
```